# I am getting a KeyError on a JSON that I scraped

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, keyerror

I have scraped a JSON from a website. When trying to iterate through the JSON I get a `KeyError`, but I'm unsure why. The loop is within the length of the JSON. Any ideas as to what is going on?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"
}
url = "https://employment.ucsd.edu/jobs?page_size=250&page_number=1&keyword=clinical%20lab%20scientist&location_city" \
      "=Remote&location_city=San%20Diego&location_city=Encinitas&location_city=Murrieta&location_city=La%20Jolla" \
      "&location_city=Not%20Specified&location_city=Vista&sort_by=score&sort_order=DESC "
request = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")
all_data = response.find_all("script", {"type": "application/ld+json"})
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=("Title", "Department", "Salary Range", "Appointment Percent", "URL"))

for data in all_data:
    jsn = json.loads(data.string)
    jsn_length = len(jsn['itemListElement'])
    # print(json.dumps(jsn, indent=4))
    n = 0
    while n < jsn_length:
        # print(jsn['itemListElement'][n])
        print(n)
        df['URL'] = jsn['itemListElement'][n]
        n += 1
```

Edit: response

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1491, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Will/PycharmProjects/UCSD_JOB_SCRAPE/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    jsn_length = len(jsn['itemListElement'])
KeyError: 'itemListElement'
```

Comment: show us the actual error - which line raises a KeyError? also to iterate over a list you can do `for item in somelist:` and can be sure to visit all items without index errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get list of URLs into a DataFrame you can use next example:

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"
}

url = (
    "https://employment.ucsd.edu/jobs?page_size=250&page_number=1&keyword=clinical%20lab%20scientist&location_city"
    "=Remote&location_city=San%20Diego&location_city=Encinitas&location_city=Murrieta&location_city=La%20Jolla"
    "&location_city=Not%20Specified&location_city=Vista&sort_by=score&sort_order=DESC "
)

request = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, "html.parser")

data = json.loads(soup.find("script", {"type": "application/ld+json"}).text)

urls = []
for e in data["itemListElement"]:
    urls.append(e["url"])

df = pd.DataFrame({"URL": urls})
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
                                                                                    URL
0      http://employment.ucsd.edu/clinical-lab-scientist-specialist-119559/job/20822209
1      http://employment.ucsd.edu/clinical-lab-scientist-specialist-120139/job/21460814
2      http://employment.ucsd.edu/clinical-lab-scientist-specialist-120483/job/21869984
3   http://employment.ucsd.edu/sr-clinical-lab-scientist-specialist-118105/job/20528292
4  http://employment.ucsd.edu/cls-clinical-lab-scientist-specialist-119095/job/20528293
```

Answer (score 2):

Element number 250 in the JSON you referenced really doesn't seem to have an `itemListElement` key:

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "url": "https://health.ucsd.edu/",
  "logo": "https://dy5f5j6i37p1a.cloudfront.net/company/logos/157272/original/b228c5f9007911ecb905ed1c0f90d00e.png",
  "name": "UC San Diego "
}
```

The safest thing is probably to explicitly check against it. E.g.:

```py
for data in all_data:
    jsn = json.loads(data.string)
    if jsn.get('itemListElement') is None:
        print('No itemListElement in the JSON. The JSON is\n' + data.string)
    else:
        jsn_length = len(jsn['itemListElement'])
        n = 0
        while n < jsn_length:
            # print(jsn['itemListElement'][n])
            print(n)
            df['URL'] = jsn['itemListElement'][n]
            n += 1
```